# Sencha Touch ScriptTagProxy only works on localhost and not pulling a remote source?

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch, script-tag

I have been spending a few days trying to get my Sencha Touch application to work, so that it uses a JSON feed to populate a news table, the code below now works fine on localhost but as soon as I change the line

```
url: 'http://localhost/list.php',
```

to a remote server:

```
url: 'http://www.myserver.com/list.php',
```

The application then fails to load and always hits the timeout listener, I have tried increasing the timeout listener to 20000 but still it does not load?

console.log(response.responseText); also fails to display anything.

Thanks Aaron

```
Ext.regStore('NotesNewsStore', {

    model: 'NoteNewsModel',

   offLineStore: new Ext.data.Store({
            model: 'photo',
            proxy: {
                type: 'localstorage',
                id: 'notes-app-store1'
            }
        }),

    proxy: {

        type: 'scripttag',
        url: 'http://localhost/list.php',
        reader: new Ext.data.JsonReader({

        }),        

        timeout:1000,
        listeners: {
            exception: function(proxy, response, operation) {
                console.log("I Think we are offline");
                    console.log(response.status);
            console.log(response.responseText);
            }
        }
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if the remote server is configured to be used with script tag, for example:

```
$callback = $_REQUEST['callback'];

// Create the output object.
$output = array('a' => 'Apple', 'b' => 'Banana');

//start output
if ($callback) {
    header('Content-Type: text/javascript');
    echo $callback . '(' . json_encode($output) . ');';
} else {
    header('Content-Type: application/x-json');
    echo json_encode($output);
}
```